# recursive function for finding dependencies

Tags: clojure

I have a collection of maps. Given any map, I want to find all the maps it depends on. Any map will have immediate dependencies. Each one of the immediate dependencies will in turn have their own dependencies, and so and so forth.

I am having trouble writing a recursive function. The code below gives a stackoverflow error. (The algorithm is not efficient anyway - I would appreciate help in cleaning it).

Below is my implementation -

`find-deps` takes a map and returns a coll of maps: the immediate dependencies of the map.

> (find-deps [m]) => coll

The function below -

1. Checks if `direct-deps`, the immediate deps,  is empty, as the base condition.
2. If not, it maps `find-deps` on all the immediate deps. This is the step
   which is causing the problem.

Usually in recursive functions we are able to narrow down the initial input, but here my input keeps on increasing !

```
(defn find-all-deps 
  ([m]
   (find-all-deps m []))
  ([m all-deps] 
    (let [direct-deps (find-deps m)]
      (if-not (seq direct-deps)
        all-deps
        (map #(find-all-deps % (concat all-deps %)) direct-deps)))))
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have a dependence loop?

Comment: Please give an example of an input that fails.

Comment: Your example code is incomplete, the find-deps function is undefined.

Comment: You seem to be using an ordered tuple (vector datatype) to store dependencies you've already found. This creates the possibility that a single dep can appear multiple times in it. You should probably switch to sets `#{}` which deduplicate so when you accept a dependency you don't then get its dependencies multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

When working with directed graphs, it's often useful to ensure that you don't visit a node in the graph twice. This problem seems a lot like many graph traversal problems out there, and your solution is very close to a normal depth-first traversal, you just need to not follow cycles (or not allow them in the input). One way to start would be to ensure that a dependency is not in the graph before you visit it again. unfortunately map is poorly suited to this, because each element in the list you are mapping over can't know about the dependencies in other elements of th same list. `reduce` is a better fit here because you are looking for a single answer.

```
...
(if-not (seq direct-deps)
    all-deps
    (reduce (fn [result this-dep] 
               (if-not (contains? result this-dep)
                 (find-all-deps this-dep (conj result this-dep))
                 result)
            direct-deps
            #{})   ;; use a set to prevent duplicates.
```